# How to set a new keybinding in Atom on osx

Tags: javascript, macos, atom-editor

I've started using Atom with a Macbook and I wanted to create a keybinding so that alt-up arrow would be page up and alt-down arrow for page down, I've tried a bunch of options and I'm not having much luck.

I'm not sure what the difference between

```
'atom-text-editor':
```

and

```
'atom-text-editor:not([mini])':
```

is and which one to use. I also have a package called emmet installed which is using alt-up and it always overrides what I'm trying, however I thought the keymap.cson file should override all 3rd party packages.

Comment: I did try following the atom guide but it wasn't clear enough for me about which class/selector I should be using and how to tell it what the command should be when I carry out a particular keystroke.

Comment: not[mini] is not minimized

Comment: Thanks but what does that mean? is it talking about the atom editor being minimized...as in on the docking toolbar? sorry I'm not sure.

Comment: No I was not right, mini is mini panels such as "goto row", "find", "command-pallete", and not[mini] means when they not shown.

Comment: so mini is whenever you have a panel pop open for instance if you're doing a search?

Comment: Right, as i said when they(mini panels) shown!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### The mini scope

The `mini` scope is for single-line inputs. For example, the "Find" or "Find in Project" panels use `mini` editors to accept input. The `not([mini])` selector excludes those, so that your binding is only used in code editor windows/panes.

In this specific case, in practice it probably doesn't matter a lot, as the mini editors won't do anything with `page-up` or `page-down` anyway. But in general, I think it is better to scope the key bindings correctly instead of just making it global. It's a good habit.

### Selectors

You already have a good selector (`atom-text-editor:not([mini])`). In the comments you asked what other selectors are (in particular, `atom-workspace` and `::shadow`). I don't have a great explanation of `::shadow` but you might read a bit including [here](http://blog.atom.io/2014/11/18/avoiding-style-pollution-with-the-shadow-dom.html).

`atom-text-editor` is scoped to, as you'd expect, text editor panes. Whereas `atom-workspace` is a bit wider scope: it is scoped to the *entire* window, which might include things like the tree view, tabs, status bars, etc.

### The ingredients of a key binding

In order to make a key binding, you need three things:

1. A selector to apply the binding to a certain scope. You already have that, as it was in your question text. `atom-text-editor:not([mini])`
2. The key binding to use. You can find those in [Atom's documentation](http://flight-manual.atom.io/behind-atom/sections/keymaps-in-depth/). In this case, we need to use `alt-up` and `alt-down`.
3. The Atom command to point each key binding to.

### How to find Atom commands

#### Using the Command Palette

Every Atom command should be available in the Command Palette (<kbd>Cmd</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>P</kbd>). In your case, you can trigger the palette and search for something like "page".

[image: Atom Command Palette]

You can see two matching commands, "Core: Page Up" and "Core: Page Down". To turn these into usable commands, you reformat them like so:

1. Remove the space after the colon
2. Replace spaces with hyphens
3. Lowercase everything

That leaves you with `core:page-up` and `core:page-down`.

#### Using the Key Binding Resolver

In some cases, you want to take a command already mapped to a key, and map it to another key. In those cases you can locate the command using Atom's Key Binding Resolver.

Activate the resolver by pressing <kbd>Cmd</kbd><kbd>.</kbd>. This will open a panel at the bottom of your window and tell you what command each keypress is tied to. Pressing <kbd>PageUp</kbd> or <kbd>PageDown</kbd> will point you to the `core:page-up` and `core:page-down` commands.

[image: Key Binding Resolver]

Press <kbd>Cmd</kbd><kbd>.</kbd> again to deactivate the Key Binding Resolver.

### Adding your keymap

In Atom's preferences, you can click "Open Config Folder" to open a new editor window with the config folder loaded. Open the `keymap.cson` file to add your new keymap.

```coffeescript
'atom-text-editor:not([mini])':
    'alt-up': 'core:page-up'
    'alt-down': 'core:page-down'
```

Save the file and your keymap should go into effect immediately.

Comment: Great post Dan, just a few questions from it.

1 - So if I leave the not(mini) bit out, it will apply to the main editor as well as things like the find input field, I guess for something like page up and down this wouldn't have any real effect so I could use either selector?

2 - If I wanted to introduce a new command that isn't shown by the keybinding resolver, how would you know what to do there?

3 - I have seen other selectors such as ::shadow and also atom-workspace, what do they mean? work-space sounds very much like atom-editor?

Comment: Also for some reason, I can't use @ with your name when leaving a comment.

Comment: Finally Dan as I mentioned in my post, the core:page-up is already bound to a 3rd party package called emmet, I think the Atom documentation said bindings in the keymap.cson file would override that but it's not happening, how can I resolve that conflict? Thanks

Comment: @jobe You can use @ for name just ignore whitespace, as for 3rd party packages the keymap.cson seems to override the keymaps from them, just tested with  'atom-text-editor':
    'ctrl-shift-m': 'editor:newline'

Comment: @BladeMight thanks but I was having a conflict when doing it with emmet for the core:page-up binding with alt-up.

Comment: @jobe I have updated my answer with responses to your questions. As for using `@`, it didn't work because you were adding a comment to my post. The system notifies me about that already, there is no need to use `@`, and the system won't let you `@` me, you can `@` other people though.

Comment: @jobe I installed Emmet and then added this keymap to `keymap.cson`, and for me, it overrides the keymap from Emmet.

Comment: @DanLowe Thanks, that's because I hadn't updated my selector, with the new one it does override it.

Comment: @jobe Keybindings resolvers says that emmet is more priority(on top) due to using not([mini]) use 'atom-text-editor:not([mini])': instead.

Answer (score 0):

To add new keybindings open the your ~/.atom/config.cson, and your own binding using example

```
'atom-text-editor':
  'ctrl-alt-b': 'atom-beautify:beautify-editor'
```

Comment: Thanks I will give this a go but I'm sure the Atom help guide is saying that you need to do this in the keymap.cson file...that's confusing, whats the difference?

Comment: @jobe I always was do it in config.cson, maybe seperating them into keymaps.cson is more convenient?  P.S. You can't remap existing keymaps, they just won't work, use Keybinding Resolver package to find out which is not binded already.

Comment: @jobe The reason to use `keymap.cson`, as stated in the docs, is that it is intentionally loaded last, so that it will always override previously-defined keymaps.